# VirtualBox VM PXE boot install fails with err:3c092003

Tags: virtualbox, pxe, isc-dhcpd, tftpd

I am using VirtualBox and have two VMs

VM A:

- NAT networking adapter
- Host-only networking adapter
- Internal Network adapter (network is called "test")

and VM B:

- Internal Network adapter (network is called "test")

I am following that article: https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall to learn how to boot a client VM (VM B) using a network boot server (VM A)

I "manually" assigned the internal adapter network card of VM A with IP

`ifconfig eth2 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

I then started the dhcp and tftp servers on VM A using the following configurations:

`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`:

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

allow booting;
option architecture-type code 93 = unsigned integer 16;

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.253;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
  option routers 192.168.0.1;             
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1; 
  filename "pxelinux.0";
}

group {
  next-server 192.168.0.1; 
  host tftpclient {
    if option architecture-type = 00:07 {
      filename "debian-installer/amd64/bootnetx64.efi";
    } else {
      filename "pxelinux.0";
    }
  }
}
```

`/etc/default/tftpd-hpa`:

```
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/srv/tftp"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

When I power-on VM B, I see

```
Waiting for link-up on net0... ok
DHCP (net0 08:00:27:3a:f4:34)...... ok
net0: 192.168.0.2/255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1
Filename: pxelinux.0
Could not start download: Operation not supported (http://ipxe.org/3c092003)
No more network devices
```

I tried googling for the err:3c092003 and saw articles suggesting:

- that I might be running VirtualBox which doesn't support HTTP (https://forum.ipxe.org/showthread.php?tid=7068) - however on iPXE welcome message I see `Features: DNS TFTP HTTP PXE PXEXT Menu` so that shouldn't be the case (HTTP is in the list)
- that I am trying to open a URI using a protocol that is not supported by my current build of iPXE (https://ipxe.org/err/3c0920), however, looking at the suggestions steps there I can't seem to find a way to fix it

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update:

I am on macOS Big Sur

VirtualBox version 6.1.28 r147628 (Qt5.6.3)

VM A and B are with Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3

Comment: You don't have to search just follow the link http://ipxe.org/3c092003 your filename has no protocol. I would use http all the way. I would also use iPXE all the way, and not pxelinux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after quite some time I got it to work.

During PXE network boot of VM B I did
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to access the iPXE command line, then `dhcp`, then `config` to see with what the DHCP server on VM A had provided VM B (as mentioned in [Error: Nothing to boot - Additional Notes](https://ipxe.org/err/2d03e1#additional_notes)).

Everything looked fine except for the fact that next-server was missing. That was weird since I had it provided in the group block of the DHCP configuration file. Anyway, after adding it in the subnet section block it magically started working.